# Extract part of path from full path Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

How can I extract

```
pathB/pathC/pathD
```

from

```
pathA/pathB/pathC/pathD/data.json
```

welcome any third party library or plain javascript

In some loader of webpack such as ng-cache-loader, I found they are able to strip the middle part of a path by specifying '//'.

From ng-cache-loader Docs:

Prefix can strip the real directory name (use //):

```
require('ng-cache?prefix=public/*//*/templates!./far/far/away/path/to/myPartial.html')
// => ng-include="'public/far/path/templates/myPartial.html'"
```

I can't find any code that process the path in ng-cache-loader source code.
Maybe I can use the same way they did to strip the middle part of path?

Comment: What is the context you will do that in? Basically I would approach it as a string parsing with available String object methods in JS or use a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

I approached your problem as a string parsing one, as mzografski mentionned. You can check this working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rqdazpan/)

Code :

```
$scope.ToExtract = 'pathB/pathC/pathD';
$scope.test = 'pathA/pathB/pathC/pathD/data.json';

$scope.extract = function(partToExtract, fullPath) {
    var index = fullPath.indexOf(partToExtract);
    return(fullPath.substring(0, index) + fullPath.substring(index+partToExtract.length+1, fullPath.length));
};

$scope.extract($scope.ToExtract, $scope.test);
```

Comment: How do you know where does the part you need to extract starts, and how do you know where it ends? Is it everything between the first "/" and the last "/" ?

Comment: yes, i always need everything between first / and last /, i have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var sep = '/';
var path = 'pathA/pathB/pathC/pathD/data.json';
path = path.split(sep);
path.shift();
path.pop();
path = path.join(sep);

// log pathB/pathC/pathD
console.log(path);
```